# Get Isar Collection from string or class variable? something like isar.${mycollection}

Tags: flutter, flutter-isar

I have created an isar helper class for all my calls to isar.  I'm trying to build generic functions. For example:

```
Future<List<dynamic>> listModel(String pModelType) async {
    final isar = await _db; 
    return isar.${pModelType}.where().findAll();       
  }
```

this doesn't work  but I'm just trying to illustrate what I'm trying to do.  I have it working with the following code expample but I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to do this?

working code:

```
  Future<IsarCollection> getIsarModel(Isar pIsar, String pModelType) async {
    
    if(pModelType == "mymodel1") {
      return pIsar.mymodel1;
    } else if (pModelType == "mymodel2"){
      return pIsar.mymodel2;
    } else {
      return pIsar.mymodel3;
    }
    
  } 

  Future<List<dynamic>> listModel(String pModelType) async {
    final isar = await _db;
    final isarModel = await getIsarModel(isar, pModelType);  
    return isarModel.where().findAll();       
  }
```

Comment: try using `getCollectionByNameInternal`

Comment: I saw that one but it doesn't work.  dart invalid_use_of_protected_member] [I] The member 'getCollectionByNameInternal' can only be used within instance members of subclasses of 'package:isar/src/isar.dart'.